# How to create a file download button? <a href> and Axios not working

Tags: vue.js, webpack, download, docx

I'm trying to create a download button on my personal website for people to download my docx resume, but had some issues.

first i did it with simple href link thingy like

```html
<a href="xxx.docx" download><button>download my resume</button></a>
```

but didn't work.

then i tried axois way, creating a button with the click action bind to the downloadFile(){} method, didn't work, coming with the error

> GET `http://localhost:8080/assets/assets/imgs/cv_eudora.docx` 404 (Not Found)
>
> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
>     at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
>     at settle (settle.js?467f:17)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:59)
> ```

[image: screenshot]

I think it's because the url part in the downloadFile(){} function that's not stated properly, but don't know the right way to write the path in vue. The path itself should be right because it even had the automatic hint options all the way when i did it.

```html
<button @click="downloadFile()">download my resume</button>
```

```js
downloadFile() {
      axios({
        url: "../assets/imgs/cv_eudora.docx",
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "blob" // important
      }).then(response => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute("download", "eudoraCV.docx"); //or any other extension
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
      });
    }
```

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't put a `<button>` inside an `<a>`. If you want your link to look like a button, use CSS to style it as such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the Webpack loaders do not apply to `<a href>` URLs so they won't be included in your build by default.

You have two options here...

1. Put your file in [the `public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder) and reference it like this

   ```js
   export default {
     // add the base URL to your component's "data" function
     data: () => ({ publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL })
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <a :href="`${publicPath}cv_eudora.docx`" download>
     download my resume
   </a>
   ```

   or
2. Explicitly import your file using the [`require()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require) function

   ```html
   <a :href="require('../assets/imgs/cv_eudora.docx')" download="cv_eudora.docx">
     download my resume
   </a>
   ```

   For this to work however, you need to configure Webpack to load `.docx` files via the `file-loader`. In `vue.config.js`, you can tell Webpack to bundle documents by adding a new module rule...

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     chainWebpack: config => {
       config.module.rule('downloads')
         // bundle common document files
         .test(/\.(pdf|docx?|xlsx?|csv|pptx?)(\?.*)?$/)
         .use('file-loader')
           // use the file-loader
           .loader('file-loader')
           // bundle into the "downloads" directory
           .options({ name: 'downloads/[name].[hash:8].[ext]' })
     }
   }
   ```

   See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#adding-a-new-loader

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr Phil. I tried the ways of yours, but only the first one worked. The second one(I actually tried it before but didn't work haha) it shows the error: `module parse failed: unexpected character '口'(1:2). You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.(source code omitted for this binary file)`

Comment: @HaiNaZheng I forgot about adding a module rule for document files so they can be loaded by the file-loader. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Phil First option worked for me , but I need the second option working for pdf. I have multiple pdf files, so I placed them under assets/pdf/sample.pdf. But when I use require my application is getting crashed..Also in the loader you have mentioned as downloads what is it significance

Comment: "downloads" is just a name, it could be anything. What error are you seeing?