# unable to load pdf - Vue

Tags: vue.js, iframe

I am facing issue in preview pdf in the browser using iframe src. The http link works fine but the pdf included in the project directory is not shown properly. I am using Vuejs.

I have a demo in 2 hrs and this is the last piece, hence I have typed this very quickly.

See code below

The 1st Iframe works fine but the second one does not. Snapshots included after the code snippet

```
<template>
  <div>  
<iframe src="https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
<iframe src="../assets/90458500ZC.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Simple option is to put the PDF in your `public` directory. See https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a file download button? <a href> and axois not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549867/how-to-create-a-file-download-button-a-href-and-axois-not-working)

Comment: Thanks @Phil - This worked like a charm. I think the stress with an upcoming demo made me panic and I missed the link.
Either ways, thanks for your immediate help. Because of u, I will look good in front of my bosses

Comment: No problem and good luck with the demo. It would be nice if Vue added some default loaders for common file types like PDF though 