# Static pdf download in Vue.js application using html download attribute

Tags: html, vue.js, webpack

I have a pdf file inside the asset folder /assets/files/test.pdf and I'm trying to enable downloading the pdf file using the html  tag as follows:

```
<a href="/files/test.pdf" download>
   <v-icon name="copy" />
</a>
```

But I kept getting "Failed - No file" in my browser when I click on the link.
My webpack is as follows:

```
{
   test: /\.(pdf)(\?.*)?$/,
   loader: 'file-loader',
   options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('files/[name].[ext]')
   }
}
```

Can anyone please let me know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Since you've already configured the loader, all you should need is to get Webpack to include the file. Try `:href="require('./relative/path/to/files/test.pdf')"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file download button? <a href> and axois not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57549867/how-to-create-a-file-download-button-a-href-and-axois-not-working)